# Should I include src code of external library or a static library built from an external library?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++. I've found a hash library I want to use: https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher

What is the right way of including that library in my own code?

Is it common to clone other repos directly into a `lib` folder and build the code within?

My folder structure is currently:

```
|-include
|   |- myfile.h
|-src
|   |- myfile.cpp
|   |- main.cpp
|-lib
|   |-smhasher
|        |- MurmurHash3.h
|        |- MurmurHash3.cpp 
|        ... etc
|- Makefile
```

and my makefile currently builds MurmurHash3.cpp before building myfile.cpp before building main.cpp

It's a bit weird to me because this setup needs to include the `smhasher` library in my source code when pushing to github for version control. I can `gitignore` the lib folder but then ppl using my code need to be aware they are required to clone `smhasher` into the `lib` folder.

Alternatively I'm wondering if I should go into the `smhasher` source code and build a static library and include that in a folder here.

Basically I'm wondering what is the most common way to handle external dependencies in c++? Are there benefits of doing it one way or the other?

Comment: `to github for version contro` there are git submodules. I usually keep all third party libraries in a .... "/third_party" folder. Each library in separate git submodule. I think this is opinion based question. It's not a programming problem. Which way you choose should be the best for you, and it's up to you (developer  / engineer) to design the best structure for your project. There is no "common way" - there are so many ways that everyone has it's own way.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way would probably be to clone the repo, put `.h`into `/include/` and `.cpp` into `/src/`. Then adjust makefile accordingly.